# AJAX methods in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

[image]

I am using many images in `UIImageView` with `UIScrollView`.

The both images have one like button when I click that like button, want to increase the likes count of the image without reload the page using background process.

How can I do this help me.

Comment: you can store the values in `UserDefaults`...

Answer (score 0):

Please use asynchronous-request to communicate with the server (No page loading issue).

As @I'M POSSIBLE says, you can used `UserDefaults` to save the like count and used `NSURLConnection` class to implement asynchronous request.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245) is a nice example given by apple on how to use `[NSURLConnection][2]` class.

On each like you can called asynchronous-request:

```
xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://yourdomain/imageLikeCount.php?"
             @"imageId=%@&likecount=%@",
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForObject:@"imageId"],
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForObject:@"ImageLikeCount"]]];    

// you can used nsurlconnection delegate method or nsoperationqueue format
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
// connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self 
// startImmediately:YES];    

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];    
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue 
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){                               
if (error) {                                   
xmlData = nil;                                   
NSLog(@"error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
 }
[xmlData appendData:data]; }];
```